# What is the problem in this loop inside a constructor function? [JS]

Tags: javascript, loops, constructor

**I am triying to create a constructor function in order to aferwards be able to instance it to create game boards objects**. The program is simple, I just passed the constructor the number of rows and it has to create them.

The for loop is not working and I dont understand the reason, ySize variable is defined. If I remove the for the program works sucessfully and create the section with no problem. **Which is the problem with the for loop?**

Thank you very much for your time

```js
function AlgorithmType(ySize) {
  this.ySize = ySize;
  this.createBoard = function() {
    let selector; let row
    for(let i = 0; i ++; i <= this.ySize) {
      debugger; // Debugger is not executed
      selector = document.querySelector(".mainContainer")
      row = document.createElement("section")
      selector.appendChild(row) 
    }
  }
}

let testBoard = new AlgorithmType(5)
testBoard.createBoard() //expected to create 5 rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function rebinds `this`, which is why `this.ySize` is not defined. Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to access `this` of the lexical scope (parent scope):

```js
function AlgorithmType(ySize) {
  this.ySize = ySize;
  this.createBoard = () => {
    let selector; let row
    for(let i = 0; i <= this.ySize; i++) {
      debugger; // Debugger is not executed
      selector = document.querySelector(".mainContainer")
      row = document.createElement("section")
      selector.appendChild(row) 
    }
  }
}
```

---

Side note: As [@atomNULL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13228285/atomnull) pointed out, your `for`-loop syntax is incorrect as well. [See his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62967499/7575111)

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop syntax is wrong, the correct syntax would be:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= this.ySize; i++)
```

Also you should use an arrow function to access this instead of rebinding it current way.